# how to build object based on user input in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, json

in my form having radio buttons , all radio button coming from json object. user click on submit button all radio button data stored into object.

```
       <form name="regForm">
       <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="q in que">
              {{q.qText}} {{$index+1}}
                <div ng-repeat="opt in q.options">
                  <input type="radio" ng-model="option" value="'{{opt}}'"/><label>{{opt}}</label>
                 </div>
                 {{option}}
            </li>
         </ul>
    <button ng-click="submitForm()">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

when user click on button . all input radio button need display in alert box how can i do it. please help me
     and json data:

```
angular.module("test",[])
.controller('ctr1', function($scope){
  $scope.ques={
    "q1": {
                "qText": " question1",
                "result":"option1",
                "options":{
                    "A":"option1",
                    "N":"option2",
                    "D":"otpion3",
                    "NA":"option4"
                }
            },
            "q2": {
                "qText": " question2",
                "result":"option1",
                "options":{
                    "A":"option1",
                    "N":"option2",
                    "D":"otpion3",
                    "NA":"option4"
                }
            },
            "q3": {
                "qText": " question3",
                "result":"option1",
                "options":{
                    "A":"option1",
                    "N":"option2",
                    "D":"otpion3",
                    "NA":"option4"
                }
            }
  }
})
```

Comment: do you want to display the object in alert? have you tried anything.Post your try.

Comment: yes, $scope.submitForm = function(){
    alert($scope.option);}

Comment: when clicked suvmitForm function is calling option object coming undefinde.

Comment: how can i get all option object, please help any one

Answer (score 0):

```
  <form name="regForm">
   <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(que,key) in ques track by $index">
          {{que.q1}} {{$index+1}}
            <div ng-repeat="(option,key2) in que[key].options">
              <input type="radio" ng-model="option.status" value="'{{option}}'"/><label>{{option}}</label>
             </div>
             {{option}}
        </li>
     </ul>
<button ng-click="submitForm()">Submit</button>
```

```
$scope.submitForm = function(){ 
 for(var que in ques){
   for(var option in ques[que].options){
     alert(ques[que].options[option].status)
    }
 }

}
```

try this it may work

In option, I am adding new field status which will give the status of the selected radio.Let me know will it work

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- As per the binding in html your your `$scope.ques` will not work. You have to modified your json.

  ```
  $scope.que=[
  {
              "qText": " question1",
              "result":"option1",
              "options":{
                  "A":"option1",
                  "N":"option2",
                  "D":"otpion3",
                  "NA":"option4"
              }
          },
          {
              "qText": " question2",
              "result":"option1",
              "options":{
                  "A":"option1",
                  "N":"option2",
                  "D":"otpion3",
                  "NA":"option4"
              }
          },
          {
              "qText": " question3",
              "result":"option1",
              "options":{
                  "A":"option1",
                  "N":"option2",
                  "D":"otpion3",
                  "NA":"option4"
              }
          }
    ];
  ```
- all radio should have `name` attribute.The name attribute is used to identify form data after it has been submitted to the server, or to reference form data using JavaScript on the client side.
  For example, you may have several radio buttons with different id attributes, but the same name. When submitted, there is just the one value in the response - the radio button you selected.

  So, `name="{{q.qText}}"`, it will be render as `name="question1"`,`name="question2"`,`name="question3"` for each set of options for a particular question.

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.que=[
    {
                "qText": " question1",
                "result":"option1",
                "options":{
                    "A":"option1",
                    "N":"option2",
                    "D":"otpion3",
                    "NA":"option4"
                }
            },
            {
                "qText": " question2",
                "result":"option1",
                "options":{
                    "A":"option1",
                    "N":"option2",
                    "D":"otpion3",
                    "NA":"option4"
                }
            },
            {
                "qText": " question3",
                "result":"option1",
                "options":{
                    "A":"option1",
                    "N":"option2",
                    "D":"otpion3",
                    "NA":"option4"
                }
            }
  ];
  
$scope.arr = [];
$scope.saveOption = function(question,selectedOpt) {
var obj = {};
obj.question = question;
obj.answer = selectedOpt;
$scope.arr.push(obj);
}

$scope.submitForm = function() {
  console.log($scope.arr);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <form name="regForm">
       <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="q in que">
              {{q.qText}} {{$index+1}}
                <div ng-repeat="opt in q.options">
                  <input type="radio" name="{{q.qText}}" ng-model="option" value="{{opt}}" ng-click="saveOption(q.qText,option)"/><label>{{opt}}</label>
                 </div>
                 {{option}}
            </li>
         </ul>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="submitForm()">Submit</button> 
</form>     
</div>
```